on-chain neural network?
I’m curious to learn if anyone has attempted to use Solana to store and run a Neural Network on-chain?
Essentially having each weight stored as an account, and each layer as an account of weight-accounts and activation-accounts. then have the on-chain program process data through a series of layer-accounts.
Probably not cost effective to train a network on-chain, but once weight values have been trained (through a system such as PyTorch) could the network be de-constructed and run on-chain?

Yes. You can use Seahorse Lang to use Python code to create Solana program, and potentially even run a neural network.
In fact, somebody did this in 2022, check this out: https://sea-nn.vercel.app/
It a convolutional neutral network trained off-chain on MNIST data and the trained model is uploaded on-chain. You draw a digit, which is sent as a parameter, and then the on-chain model returns prediction output in program logs.

Fantastic!  Thank you.
